# SSIS move to Fact and dimensions

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, etl

Ok so I am trying to get a simple data warehouse built to run a report against.

I have three tables that I managed to get imported from two csv files and a view in a separate database.

I want to split out the columns (none of which have any keys setup yet) into dimensions and fact tables.

Should I go about this by just building a big script that just builds all the tables and creates keys for each one or is there an easier way.

The obstacles around the import took me days to get around so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: On a very high level, you can use SSIS to import data into SQL tables directly from the data sources(viz. 2 excel files and a view). But of course, you would have to first create the tables first. And you would have to define basic relationships between the tables so that they can be joined.

Comment: Unless there's some reason not to, I'd build a big script (or several small ones) just as you've described.